# How to use json response with relationship

Tags: laravel, modal-dialog, pivot-table

I want to fetch data from the pivot table `platform_user`. I am able to get the ID of the user using ajax. PLease see my code below.

Controller

```
public function show($id) {
    $users_id = User::find($id);
    $users_id->with('platforms')->where('id', $id)->get();
    return response()->json($users_id);
}
```

Blade - I am using bootstrap modal to get the USER ID and NAME in pop modal. However, I need to fetch data for that USER ID related to the pivot table.

```
<select name="platform" id="platform" class="form-control">
    @if(isset($users_id))
        @foreach($users_id as $user_platform)
            @foreach($user_platform->platforms as $platform)
                    <option value="{{$platform->id}}">{{$platform->title}}</option>
            @endforeach
        @endforeach
    @endif
</select>
```

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('body').on('click', '#show_user', function () {
        var userURL = $(this).data('url');
        $.get(userURL, function (data) {
            $('#removePlatformModal').modal('show');
            $('#user_id').text(data.id);
            $('#user_name').text(data.name);
        })
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using [whereHas]:

```
public function show($id) {
    $users_id = User::find($id);

    $users_id->whereHas('platforms', function($query) use ($user_id){
     $query->where('id', $user_id);
})->get();

    return response()->json($users_id);
}
```